# Bootstrap 3 - button in Input Group not in the same height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3, use input group, use button and use glyphicon for the button, but strangely the buttons are not the same height, how do I make the height of the buttons the same?

[image]

My simple coding is like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<div class='input-group'>
    <span class='input-group-addon'>Nama</span>
    <input type='text' id='enomor' class='form-control' onkeypress='return okpnons(event)'>
    <span id='enomorupdate'  class='input-group-btn'>
        <button type='button' onclick='ocenomorupdate()' class='btn btn-primary'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the correct syntax. I've changed the `input-group-btn` container from a `span` element to a `div` element.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class='input-group'>
  <span class='input-group-addon'>Nama</span>
  <input type='text' id='enomor' class='form-control' onkeypress='return okpnons(event)'>
  <div class='input-group-btn'>
    <button type='button' onclick='ocenomorupdate()' class='btn btn-primary'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also adjust the height of the button manually to match the height of the bootstrap 3 input using custom CSS:

```
.input-group .form-control,
.input-group-btn .btn {
    height: 34px;
}
.input-group-addon,
.form-control,
.input-group-btn .btn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I've tried uploading your coding, but why is it still not working for me? hahahaha, very strange, the height is still different

Comment: @Junaserbaserbi That suggests you likely either have custom CSS overriding bootstrap styles (which you should include in your question) or you're not using the bootstrap version you specified.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
I used this before, but I have copied the CSS link from you, but the result is still the same, the height is still different

Comment: I don't use CSS at all, just the bootstrap.min.css link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256298/discussion-between-jacob-and-juna-serbaserbi).

Comment: I only use this in CSS: body{background-color:black;}

Comment: Thank you Jacob, it works for me from your css solution.